# Possible to make these two django views DRY-er?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, dry

I'm currently learning the Python / Django stack by following some training to build a blog.

I currently have two similar views for adding new and editing existing posts (post_new and post_edit) as below:

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect("post_detail", pk=post.pk)      
    else:
        form = PostForm()    
    return render(request, "blog/post_edit.html", {"form": form})


def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user 
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect("post_detail", pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, "blog/post_edit.html", {"form":form})
```

Although these views do different jobs they share some identical code.

Trying to follow best practice (DRY), is there a sensible way to make such similar views DRYer? Or is it better to leave views of this sort of length in long form to keep them easy to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally write it like this:

```
def post_edit(request, pk=None):
    if pk is not None:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    else:
        post = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user 
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect("post_detail", pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, "blog/post_edit.html", {"form":form})
```

Basically, you pass the default `instance` value to the `ModelForm`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/) for that.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView

class PostCreate(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['name', ...]

class PostUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['name', ...]
```

Comment: Switching to class based views doesn't solve the duplicated code problem. The code that sets the author and published date will be duplicated, unless you create a mixin. This isn't necessarily any better than a single function like Gert suggested.